# Grails 2.4 plugin Rendering skipping non latin characters and return blank pdf file

Tags: pdf, grails, character-encoding, rendering

I think that I have similar problem or at least with close solution.

**Details:

1. OS          - windows 7(also tried one mint 17 with the same result);
2. IDE         - GGTS (Groovy-Grails Tool Suite 3.2.0.RELEASE)
3. grails      - 2.4;
4. pluggin     - Grails Rendering (http://grails.org/plugin/rendering)

**

Basically I'm following this article in order to get a pdf file based on a template: http://www.icodeya.com/2012/09/grails-how-do-i-render-gsp-files-in-pdf.html . Everything is going fine until there are some characters different than latin1 - for example Cyrillic or Portuguese. I'm able to bypass the problem with:

```
...  
def renderer = new ITextRenderer()  
FontResolver resolver = renderer.getFontResolver() 
    **.getFontResolver.addFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED_SUBSET);**
...
```

but the text in the pdf file is badly formatted - original text:

> quick fox

, in the pdf file is:

> qu i ck fo x

. Some extra spaces appear in the text.

All settings that I could found are changed to use UTF-8: gsp, text, html files. 
Thank in advance, 
             Ivo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to plugin documentation:

> The solution is to register the font to use with a particular
>   encoding. Because we are using XHTMLRenderer we can specify this in
>   CSS as opposed to programatically registering.

So place in your gsp page, head section the following

```
<style>
    @font-face {
      src: url(path/to/arial.ttf);
      -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
      -fs-pdf-font-encoding: cp1250;
    }
    body {
      font-family: "Arial Unicode MS", Arial, sans-serif;
    } </style>
```

and if it is not enough add in: grails-app\services\grails\plugin\rendering\pdf\PdfRenderingService.groovy

```
...  
def renderer = new ITextRenderer()  
FontResolver resolver = renderer.getFontResolver() 
    **.getFontResolver.addFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED_SUBSET);**
...
```